# Watch and compile entire folder with node-sass?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

Compass has a lovely command that will watch and compile all scss in a given directory:

```
compass watch *foldername*
```

However, the Ruby-based compass is kind of slow and the C-based SASSC, wrapped in the form of node-sass, is much faster. Thing is, I haven't been able to replicate this seemingly simple feature using node-sass.

I followed the directions given here: http://benfrain.com/lightning-fast-sass-compiling-with-libsass-node-sass-and-grunt-sass/, which do a great job of setting up node-sass with grunt to watch for file changes, but it doesn't seem to support watching and converting an entire folder, agnostic of the file names within.

I've tried changing the

```
sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'css/styles.css': 'sass/styles.scss'
            }
        }
    }
```

values to the folders, amongst many other things, and nothing seems to work. I'll admit that I don't really know anything about grunt. Is there a way to replicate

```
compass watch *folder*
```

or

```
sass --watch *folder*:*folder*
```

that I haven't tried, or does this not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaniv was on the right track, but the magic seemed to be in "expand". Here's what ended up working:

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['sitecontent/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    }
```

This compiles all sass files in the sitecontent folder and all subfolders and puts the css next to the sass file - it doesn't compile them to some other folder.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use grunt-sass in combination with grunt-contrib-watch to get the same affect. The ruby version uses a separate gem to accomplish the file watching functionality, so you can imagine how difficult that is to do cross platform in C++.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. The chokidar npm module makes watches rather easy (and very multiplatform). I'm using it, and a Makefile, for all my JavaScript and CSS build needs. I refuse to see why each tool should have its own watch etc. The state of the JavaScript build cacophony is horrendous. There are ways out. Please ask me by private message. :)

Comment: Yes, there is a PR to swap the existing watch functionality to chokidar https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/844

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        src: ['*.scss'],
        dest: '../public',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  }
```

Hope that was what you were looking for